# Hartl Rails section 8.3 rspec error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

I'm working through the hartl rails tutorial

I'm at the end of section 8.3, the application is functioning correctly but I'm getting an rspec error

```
1) User pages signup with valid information after saving the user 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out') }
   expected link "Sign out" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:48:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

the part of user_pages_spec.rb that is involved in this is

```
it "should create a user" do
    expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end  
  describe "after saving the user" do
    it { should have_link('Sign out') }
  end
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to fix this.  There are other posts around similar to this but alas, I can't get their solutions to work in my case.  thanks.

Comment: Try adding `before { click_button submit }` inside the `describe`, [like this](http://pastebin.com/tJTzhYRZ). If that doesn't work can you post your `UsersController#create` code.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need to Create the account before checking for the link.  There is more to the tests than you posted.  Here is a snippet of the code I used when going through the tutorial.

```
describe "after saving the user" do
  before { click_button "Create my account" }
  it { should have_link('Sign out') }
end
```

Comment: I Would expect the code inside 'it should create a user' to do the creation. Isn't this so?

Comment: After the "should create a user" test, the test conditions reset.